# Custom packet over TCP/IP?

Tags: python, packet, tcp

I'm new in Python programming but i have a big problem: how can i custom packet over TCP/IP in Python.
Any solutions ?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom packet"? Custom data? or custom envelopes?

Comment: TCP/IP provides a stream of bytes you have little/no control over packetizing... *so*, could you rephrase your question?

Comment: I need it to send packet in HL7 format to external app.
Then I need to parse ack come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).